# Jaspersoft Studio App Transport Security - unable to load reports

Tags: http, security, https, jaspersoft-studio

I'm trying to edit reports in Jaspersoft Studio but am being blocked with this error when attempting to load the report:

> Page load failed with error: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.

My colleagues are loading reports from the same server (http) running the same version of Jaspersoft Studio without issue. I have reached out to their support with no response.
It seems most other threads on this subject are not specific to Jaspersoft and recommend altering Info.plist but I don't believe Jaspersoft utilizes this file. Is there another location or setting I can alter to allow this connection?

Answer (score 0):

Correction: There is an info.plist file for Jasperstudio. I was able to locate it and inserted this code:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

This solved the error.

Comment: Unfortunately the reports are blank when loaded now.